# converting base class pointer to unknown derived class pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract

I have 5 derived classes from an abstract base class. **One function** is overloaded which exists **in every derived class**, let's name it, `print()`. Example for Derived 4 class:

```
Derived4::print(*Derived1)
Derived4::print(*Derived2)
Derived4::print(*Derived3)
Derived4::print(*Base)
```

Like i said before, all derived classes have print function, but arguments are different, like

```
Derived1::print(*Derived2)
Derived1::print(*Derived3)
Derived1::print(*Derived4)
Derived1::print(*Base)
```

All objects are stored inside a vector like

```
vector<Base*> a
```

When i take one of them from vector and try to call print function, all calls are directed to print(*Base) function.I am not allowed to store the types, therefore don't have any idea what is coming from vector.Also, type checking is not allowed too.

An example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
    void print(){cout << "greetings from A" << endl;}
};

class C : public A{
public:
    void print(){cout << "greetings from C" << endl;}
};

class D : public A{
public:
    void print(){cout << "greetings from D" << endl;}
}; 

class B : public A{
public:
    void print(C* c){c->print();}
    void print(A* d){d->print();}
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    C c;
    B b;
    vector<A*> a; //B,C,D will be stored inside a vector like this.
    a.push_back(&c);
    a.push_back(&d);
    b.print(a[0]);
    b.print(a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The result:

```
greetings from A
greetings from A
```

The desired result:

```
greetings from C
greetings from A
```

Comment: In your explanation every class has a different `print` function (different parameters) while in your example all of them (except `B`) have a same one (same parameters) - which one is it?

Comment: Check out the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: However in general for downcasting you should use `dynamic_cast` and check if the cast succeeded (returned a non-null value)

Comment: Don't mind about the example code,i only filled class B.All i want is to show an example about the result.

Comment: Why don't you polymorphism?

Comment: "Don't mind about the example code" No, we should worry about it. You need to post all the code necessary to understand and solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need virtual functions. declaring `A::print` as virtual would make it so that calling print on a pointer of type `A` will call the `print` of which class the object was constructed as, instead of using pointer type to decide what `print` to call.

You also need to remove `D::print` as you expect `A::print` get called if the object is of type `D`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
    virtual void print(){ cout << "This is printed twice." << endl; }
};

class C : public A{
public:
    void print(){ cout << "This is desired output." << endl; }
};

class D : public A{

};

class B : public A{
public:
    void print(C* c){ c->print(); }
    void print(A* d){ d->print(); }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    C c;
    B b;
    vector<A*> a; //B,C,D will be stored inside a vector like this.
    a.push_back(&c);
    a.push_back(&d);
    b.print(a[0]);
    b.print(a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The result:

```
This is desired output.
This is printed twice.
```